# Error "no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path" installing TeamCity on Windows Server 2012

Tags: java, windows, teamcity, windows-server-2012

I am installing TeamCity on a Windows 2012 Server. I'm at the database connection setup screen but getting this error.

> "SQL error when doing: Taking a connection from the data source: no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path"

I've copied the `sqljdbc_auth.dll` to the `C:\Windows\System32` folder and added a system environment variable `java.library.path` that points to this folder.

Answer (score 18):

Teamcity installs the 32-bit version even if you're on a 64-bit platform unless you deliberately use 64-bit.  So I am just going to give you the 32-bit instructions for using Windows authentication with Teamcity SQL database setup.  The instructions are the same for the 64-bit setup, just change x86 to x64

1. Create an empty database in SQL server
2. Make sure the Windows account configured on the TeamCity service(s) have access to the database
3. Copy sqljdbc42.jar to `<TeamCity_data_dir>\lib\jdbc\sqljdbc42.jar`
4. Copy `auth\x86\sqljdbc_auth.dll` from the Microsoft download to `<TeamCity_data_dir>\lib\sqljdbc_auth.dll`
5. Open System > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables and add a System variable TEAMCITY_SERVER_OPTS set to the value `-Djava.library.path=<TeamCity_data_dir>\lib` or run `setx TEAMCITY_SERVER_OPTS=-Djava.library.path=<TeamCity_data_dir>\lib`
6. Click OK on all dialogs and restart the Teamcity services.

Now you can connect Teamcity to the SQL server using Windows Authentication after which the wizard will create the database.

#### Edit: January 27, 2020

With the 2019.2.1 update I've had to move the sql_jdbcauth.dll file to `<TeamCity_data_dir>\system\caches\jdbc\native\windows-i386`  This could be just a bug in the upgrade process.

Comment: this should be how the TeamCity instructions are written, not their current documentation which got me nowhere.. thanks a lot for this answer

Comment: Step 5 is confusing. Server 2016 has an improved dialog box that requires you to separate the variable name and variable value. The correct variable name is `TEAMCITY_SERVER_OPTS` and the correct variable value is `-Djava.library.path=<TeamCity_data_dir>\lib`, of course substituting `<TeamCity_data_dir>` for your actual teamcity data dir path.

Answer (score 7):

This

http://www.mikeobrien.net/blog/teamcity-sqlserver-integrated-security

helped me.

I used the JDBC 4.1 version.

Comment: I upvoted as it helped me a lot - but I would suggest putting some more info beside link. All is summarized to this: replace TC jre with x64 jre.

Comment: Or if you're running on 32 bit, just drop the x86 version of `sqljdbc_auth.dll` (from the jdbc download) into `<TeamCityProgramDir>\bin`

Comment: @BrianLacy this is the only thing that worked for me, thanks. You should add it as an answer.

Answer (score 6):

I managed to resolve the issue by using SQL Server authentication instead of Windows authentication during the database configuration setup. Not sure why this should have fixed the error as it relates to a Java environment variable, but I can only assume that the error was generated by it's failure to login to the database and for some reason threw an unrelated error instead.

This appears to be an error with TeamCity throwing the wrong error message. If you get this error, try switching to SQL Server authentication.

Comment: Windows authentication has specific configuration requirements - access to the Microsoft provided DLL to support it. Normal SQL authentication does not require this.  See my answer.

Comment: You have to provide path to dll `-Djava.library.path=path/to/dll`, please read more here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50115530/6655459

Comment: Switching from Windows Authentication to SQL Server authentication just to fix a file not found error is like using a cannon to kill a mosquito

Answer (score 6):

If you're running on 32-bit, you can just copy the x86 version of `sqljdbc_auth.dll` (from the jdbc download) into `<TeamCityProgramDir>\bin`.

Comment: This worked for me in the migration step. But when running TeamCity afterwards, it still couldn't find the file. So I ended up copying the file to `TeamCityProgramDir\bin` AND `TeamCityProgramDir\lib`, and it's all fine now.

Comment: this should be the answer!

Comment: Files in the `bin` folder get moved during automatic TeamCity updates: _[2019-03-19 16:18:14,375]   INFO -   jetbrains.buildServer.UPDATE - Moving C:\TeamCity\bin\sqljdbc_auth.dll to .old_

Answer (score 1):

You should check your TeamCity server log. Mine (located at `c:\TeamCity\logs\teamcity-server.log`) mentions the following:

> [2019-03-20 07:54:56,045]   INFO -  jetbrains.buildServer.STARTUP - Native library sqljdbc_auth.dll was not found under either E:\BuildServer\lib\jdbc\native\windows-i386 or E:\BuildServer\lib\jdbc\native; will continue looking in sun.boot.library.path and java.library.path.

After putting the `sqljdbc_auth.dll` library in `E:\BuildServer\lib\jdbc\native\windows-i386` and restarting the service everything was fine and dandy; without having to meddle with `bin` folders (they get reset during TC upgrades) or having to define environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it didn't worked because there were some files from previous install and version TeamCity isntallation. I uninstalled TeamCity, deleted all TeamCity folders and installed again. Then it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this issue today with TeamCity 10.x, with bundled Java, and I wanted to migrate an existing, internal, database to SQL Server.

1. Follow [Setting up TeamCity with MS SQL Server](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Setting+up+TeamCity+with+MS+SQL+Server) until you need to setup the JDBC Driver.
2. Log into your TeamCity server with the same Windows account you setup SQL Server with.
3. With the current version they say to download the 6.0+ driver, but then reference the 4.x version. You want the version at **Downloads\Microsoft JDBC Driver 6.2 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_6.2\enu\mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar**, and to copy it to **C:\ProgramData\JetBrains\TeamCity\lib\jdbc\mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar**.
4. From that same 6.x driver download, copy **Downloads\Microsoft JDBC Driver 6.2 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_6.2\enu\auth\x86\sqljdbc_auth.dll** to **C:\ProgramData\JetBrains\TeamCity\lib\sqljdbc_auth.dll**.
5. Add a new System Environment Variable called `TEAMCITY_SERVER_OPTS` with the value of `-Djava.library.path=C:\ProgramData\JetBrains\TeamCity\lib`.
6. So that the MaintainDB tool works, add another System Environment Variable called `TEAMCITY_MAINTAINDB_OPTS` with the same value (`-Djava.library.path=C:\ProgramData\JetBrains\TeamCity\lib`).

Now you can run MaintainDB without getting an error about the sqljdbc_auth.dll not being in the JAVA library path.

See [Creating Backup via maintainDB command-line tool - maintainDB Startup Options](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Creating+Backup+via+maintainDB+command-line+tool#CreatingBackupviamaintainDBcommand-linetool-maintainDBStartupOptions) for why both environment variables need to be set.