# Using windows authentication for SQL Server JDBC with pyspark

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, windows-authentication

I want to ask how can I connect the SQL Server using Windows Authentication, with pyspark library? I can connect with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio but not when I try to code in Python with a spark.Here's what I tried so far.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
    .config("spark.driver.extraClassPath","mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar") \
    .getOrCreate()

mssql_df = spark.read.format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=DATABASE-NAME") \
    .option("dbtable", "database-table-name") \
    .option("user", "Windows-Username") \
    .option("password", "Windows-Pass")\
    .option("driver", 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver').load()

mssql_df.printSchema()
mssql_df.show()
```

Comment: And the result is that:

py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o39.load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url?view=sql-server-2017) you can set the `integratedSecurity=true` to connect to SQL Server via jdbc and Windows Authentication.

Then Spark configuration it should look as next:

```
mssql_df = spark.read.format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=DATABASE-NAME;integratedSecurity=true") \
    .option("dbtable", "database-table-name") \
    .option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver") \
    .load()
```

**UPDATE:**

As discussed in the comments user should place `sqljdbc_auth.dll` in the same folder where `mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre12.jar` lives or just set `spark.driver.extraClassPath` for both jars seperated by : as shown below:

```
.config("spark.driver.extraClassPath","/path.to/mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar:/path/to/sqljdbc_auth.dll")
```

sqljdbc_auth.dll is part of the Microsoft JDBC Driver 6.0 for SQL Server  and you can download it from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774). Alternatively you can just install JDBC driver on your system and specify the path where the dll is stored.

Comment: Now I have another problem. The problem now is located on the SparkSession. On the 

.config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre12.jar").

Rise an issue:
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

How can I fix this?

Comment: where is the mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar located? you should specify the absolute path for this .jar explicitly

Comment: an alternative would be to move the mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar file under the jars folder which is the default location for all the jars in my case the path is: `C:\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7\jars`

Comment: I moved the jar file to my spark folder as you said and also I gave the absolute path but still the same problem I have. There is another configuration that I can use?

Comment: ok so where are you running your spark job? also how the line `.config("spark.driver.extraClassPath","mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar")` looks like at the moment?

Comment: I run it from Pycharm IDE (I do not know if answer well your question). My current line is now `.config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "C:\\Users\\renos.bardis\\Desktop\\mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre12.jar")` 

Also, I have this problem sometimes `py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o37.load.` 

How can I vanish all the WARNING like `WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform (file:/C:/Spark/Spark/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/spark-unsafe_2.11-2.4.3.jar) to method java.nio.Bits.unaligned()`

Comment: ok the .jar is indeed in your desktop? is the previous path correct? in this case I would really suggest to place it elsewhere ie under the jars folder of Spark

Comment: After some modifications, I do not have the problem for the file path but with:

`py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o37.load.
: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication. ClientConnectionId:26acbe77-7e4b-4c4d-8a05-37786ae7f335
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:2924)
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI.<init>(AuthenticationJNI.java:73)`

Comment: ok so the issue is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48169801/sqlexception-this-driver-is-not-configured-for-integrated-authentication-tomcat) you need to specify the path for sqljdbc_auth.dll. You can search if it is present already in your system or download it from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774). In both cases you will need it to copy sqljdbc_auth.dll into the folder where `mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre12.jar` is

Comment: The problem fixed. Thank you @AlexandrosBiratsis

Comment: I followed all your instructions but I have a problem when I use `df.count()` the program shows `pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: 'Unsupported class file major version 56'`. How can I fix this (My java version is 1.8.0_221)

Comment: when I put on Pycharm these commands
`import findspark
import os
spark_location='C:\\Spark\\Spark\\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7' # Set your own
java8_location= 'C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_201' # Set your own
os.environ['JAVA_HOME'] = java8_location
findspark.init(spark_home=spark_location)` 

I have this issue:
`: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerDriver has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 56.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
`

Comment: Hi Reno the problem is that the jdbc driver in incompatible with the Java version in your system. So you should try to sync those two either but installing a different Java version or another jdbc version

Comment: Again I tried different things but the same thing: `pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: 'Unsupported class file major version 56` when I use the command `df.count()`. Really I do not know what else to do.

Comment: No worries everything is solvable. What is the version of the Java and the MS JDBC driver in your system? The Java version you can find with ’java -version’ and the jdbc just check the dll version

Comment: I use now "12.0.2" java version and mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre12 and sqljdbc_auth.dll (x64)  and still when I type the command `df.count()`  I have this problem `pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: 'Unsupported class file major version 56'`

Comment: Also when I use java8 I have the Runtime problem with the versioning and when I switch I have the above problem and I do not understand at all.

Comment: Can you post the whole error message? These two problems dont seem to be related

Comment: The message is huge how can I put it all here?

Comment: You can't maybe you should create a new question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198723/discussion-between-alexandros-biratsis-and-renos-bardhis).